# c# with database mysql workbench

Tags: c#, mysql

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          try
            {
                string strInsert = "INSERT INTO data.hm(num, messagev) VALUES('"               +textBox1.Text + "', '" + textBox2.Text + "');";
                cmd = new MySqlCommand(strInsert, connection);
                connection.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                connection.Close();
                MessageBox.Show("yes", "test");
                this.Close();
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("not", "test");
            }

        }
```

i work with mysql workbench 5.2ce
Im 2 column in my database(teble hm)  first column (num int(10)),seconde column  (messagev varchar(255))  this code not working  please i want the solution ?

Comment: remove the try/catch block and let the exception  message show. Then write here what is the error message

Comment: can we have dot in table name?

Comment: we are assuming you have a schema aka dbname `data`, and in that a table named `hm`. Correction, I am assuming that

Comment: surround your table name with backticks `data.hm`. I can get it to work. But I would advise against a tablename with a dot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't have table names with a dot. Keep that for database name references. Things are tricky enough without that added mess.

Surround tablenames with back-ticks when in doubt.

```
create table this.that
(   id int not null
);
```

> Error Code: 1049. Unknown database 'this'

```
create table `this.that`
(   id int not null
);
```

-- success

```
insert into this.hm (id) values(7);
```

> Error Code: 1146. Table 'this.hm' doesn't exist

```
insert into `this.hm` (id) values(7);
```

-- success

### Exception Handling

Instead of home-grown unhelpful error messages in the development phase at least, do not override exception info as such. Display something useful.

```
catch (MySqlException ex)
{   Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", ex.ToString());
}
```